# Xamarin Android WebView KeyUp and KeyDown events

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, keypress

I have a problem that WebView consumes the key events and i don't get them in the Activity where i catch the KeyUp and Down, I need them because i use hardware with extra hardware buttons and i need to know when they are pressed.

is there some way to catch the events on the View or is there any way to detect globally KeyUp and KeyDown?

I tried override the WebViewRenderer but with no luck

Comment: using the dispatchKeyEvent is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dispatchKeyEvent is thrown allways first and then the Key events are thrown